# Why does adding a secondary index to a dynamodb table via cdk requires a recreation of the table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

adding a secondary index to a (previously via cdk deployed) dynamodb table like

```
table.addLocalSecondaryIndex({
  indexName: "indexName",
  sortKey: {
    name: "keyName",
    type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING,
  },
  projectionType: dynamodb.ProjectionType.INCLUDE,
  nonKeyAttributes: ["attr1", "attr2"],
});
```

requieres a recreation of the table as seen in the cloudformation change set created by cdk:

```
    "resourceChange": {
      "logicalResourceId": "---ID---",
      "action": "Modify",
      "physicalResourceId": "---ID---",
      "resourceType": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "replacement": "True",
      "moduleInfo": null,
      "details": [
        {
          "target": {
            "name": "LocalSecondaryIndexes",
            "requiresRecreation": "Always",
            "attribute": "Properties"
          },
          "causingEntity": null,
          "evaluation": "Static",
          "changeSource": "DirectModification"
        }
      ],
      "changeSetId": null,
      "scope": [
        "Properties"
      ]
    },
    "type": "Resource"
  }
```

1. Why is that?
2. Can that be prevented somehow or is there a Workaround besides adding the index manually via the aws-console?

Cheers,
Helge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is that?

Changes to [LocalSecondaryIndexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-lsi) require **replacement** of DynamoDB table, since LSI can only be created on the table create time. In contrast, modifications to [GlobalSecondaryIndexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-gsi) lead to **no interruption**.

> Can that be prevented somehow or is there a Workaround besides adding the index manually via the aws-console?

Sadly, there is no way to prevent this, as explained above. You can **use GSI** if you don't want to keep replacing your tables.

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaking Global and Local secondary indexes. Local can not be created after table creation, only global can. That's the reason your code fails.